# Bot Framework SDK 4.11 DialogContextError: Cannot read property 'trackTrace' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'trackTrace' of undefined

Tags: dialog, botframework

I am facing an error after updating Microsoft botbuilder and botbuilder-dialog version 4.11.0. It's working fine with the earlier versions.

Below error encountered after updating to version 4.11.0

```
{ TypeError: Cannot read property 'trackTrace' of undefined
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ashokmanseta/Projects/botbuilder-adapter/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/src/dialogContainer.ts:49:40)
  at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
  at fulfilled (/Users/ashokmanseta/Projects/botbuilder-adapter/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/dialogContainer.js:4:58)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
name: 'DialogContextError',
dialogContext:
 { activeDialog: 'dialog-0.2220127757',
   parent: undefined,
   stack: [ [Object] ] } }
```

Kindly help if any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code dies on checking telemetryclient for dialogs in dialogContainer

```
dc.dialogs.telemetryClient.trackTrace({
message: traceMessage,
severityLevel: botbuilder_core_1.Severity.Warning,
});
```

To add telemetry client which can be a NullTelemetryClient

Check where you are creating a dialogContext on the main dialog,

```
//Example
const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(context);
```

put this line there

```
import { NullTelemetryClient } from "botbuilder";
dialogContext.dialogs.telemetryClient=new NullTelemetryClient()
```